# PHP: Parse Error in script importing csv data

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import-from-excel

I have created this small script in order to parse a cvs file and then pass it on to mysql. I need to do quite some editing to it but I just started with editing the format of the date according to the http://csv.thephpleague.com manual.

```
<?php

    if (!ini_get("auto_detect_line_endings")) {
        ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", '1');
    }

    use League\Csv\Reader;

    $reality = Reader::createFromPath('Workbook3.csv');
    $planed = Reader::createFromPath('Workbook4.csv');

    /*this function removes the "First name" "Second name" elements and 
    creates one that actually has the entier name in capital*/
    $functionHRT = function ($row) {
        $row['hrtData'] => DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat($row['Contract Start'], 'd-m-Y'); /*this is line 18*/
    }

    $hrtData = $reality
                // ->setOffset(7);
                ->fetchAssoc( , $functionHRT());
    $hrtData[0]['Contract Start']->format('Y-m-d');        

    ?>
```

When I try to run this I get an:

```
Parse error: parse error in /Users/nefeli/Code/ph/script.php on line 18
```

error code. I am not sure what the problem syntax error is. Any insight on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line has a syntax error:

```
$reality->fetchAssoc( , $functionHRT());
```

According to the [docs](http://csv.thephpleague.com/reading/) this is the method's signature:

> **fetchAssoc($offset_or_keys = 0, callable $callable = null)**

So, if you want to pass the callback you have to specify also the first parameter to the function. You can use the default (0) and pass the callback as the second parameter.

Also remember that when you're passing the callback you don't have to call it (using the parentheses like you're doing) but you only need to specify the variable, as you've previously declared the [lamba function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) and stored it in the `$functionHRT` variable

So your call should be:

```
$reality->fetchAssoc( 0, $functionHRT );
```

---

Another error is in the statement:

```
$functionHRT = function ($row) {
    $row['hrtData'] => DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat($row['Contract Start'], 'd-m-Y'); /*this is line 18*/
}
```

You're using the wrong operator to assign a value to the array. It should be:

```
$functionHRT = function ($row) {
    $row['hrtData'] = DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat($row['Contract Start'], 'd-m-Y'); /*this is line 18*/     
};
```

You need also to add a semicolon at the end of the callback's declaration

Comment: thanks a lot for noticing! Do you have any ideas about the parsing error though?

Comment: @Byte_Monster: In PHP you can only leave out function arguments when they have a default value _and_ come last. ``fetchAssoc(, $callback)`` is therefore not possible. You _have_ to fill in the first argument. ``fetchAssoc()``, ``fetchAssoc(1)`` or ``fetchAssoc(0, $callback)`` are possible. Second, you don't add parentheses to a callback.

Comment: thanks a lot I fixed this. But please stay with me for a moment because I must have made a mistake while using League.

I run the composer just as the Docks suggested
`$ composer require league/csv`
But now I am getting the error:
`Fatal error: Class 'League\Csv\Reader' not found in /Users/me/Code/script.php on line 12`

I am on Mac os and the composer did run correctly. Am I doing something wrong with the syntax?

Comment: actually I found the issue: I did not use `include 'vendor/autoload.php';
` . Thanks a lot people! this was extremely useful.

Comment: @Byte_Monster : to accept an answer you should click on the 'check mark' under the up/downvote arrows :)